# Bootstrap/Grunt Query

Tags: html, npm, grunt

I have never used bootstrap and i'm not quite sure how it works, so there are a couple of things I want to know:

Do I really need `grunt`?

I created a folder Bootstrap Project". Once I was inside, I added `npm`. After that `npm install -g grunt-cli` to add `grunt`. Finally, I did `npm install bootstrap`.

The problem is that I don't know what else do I have to do to start working on my project.

Do I have to create an `HTML` and add the code of bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referencing [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), you do not need grunt for anything other than compiling Bootstrap itself from LASS/SASS you can customize.

All you need to get started with Bootstrap is jQuery, bootstrap.css, and bootstrap.js in your HTML file, which you could even get from a remote source like cdnjs. You can see this in action on Bootstrap's [Getting Started page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template).